# How to install npm dependencies and devDependencies to separate directories?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I need to npm install package.json `devDependencies` to `node_modules` folder (native behavior), but `dependencies` to `project/node_modules`.

What I should to write in package.json (or other) config?

Comment: @ajduke I use modules from devDependencies for builder and modules from dependencies (like Angular, jQuery, require.js, etc) I use in project folder.

I have index.html in the project folder, that is why I do not to install project dependencies in parent folder

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I hate that everything goes into node_modules, especially when gulp has tons of dependencies and bootstrap is just one folder that occasionally changes structure.